# Can't find namespace (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, namespaces

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project in Visual Studio. I have a solution set up that contains two seperate projects. I'm new to ASP.NET and I think I'm missing something basic as I cant reference classes out-with the Project that the class trying to reference is located in.

Just to clarify:

I have projectA that contains classA.
I have projectB that contains classB.

I type this into classA:

using Solution.projectB.classB

I get an error saying that projectB does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project A needs a Project Reference to Project B, i.e. right-click on Project A, select Add Reference, select Projects, and select Project B.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Marty, I knew I was missing something basic (this is still quite new to me, just moved over from PHP so it's very different). Looks like this website will be a valuable resource for me. Thanks Marty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference from project A into project B or visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference to the namespace and not directly to the class.
Try changing your `using` to:

```
using Solution.projectB;
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET can see namespaces across the same project.  By default, it cannot see namespaces across different projects in the same solution.  You need to add a reference from the top level project "A" to the dependent project "B".

[How to: Add a Project Reference to a Visual Studio Web Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx)

After adding the reference, let Visual Studio do the heavy lifting.  Type

`classB instanceOfB = new classB();` (assuming there's a default constructor)

Use your mouse to click on classB.  Hit the shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.  This will open up a drop down giving you the option to automatically import the namespace.

Visual Studio will use [syntax coloring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265717%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to let you know that the process was successful.  Alternatively, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to compile the project.